# VBA autocomplete drop down list not picked up by data validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation, combobox, autocomplete

Here is a challenge : I have created a dropdown list with an autocompletion feature using a ComboBox (I have used the instructions from this article http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html). This feature is invoqued with double clicking on the cell that contains the list and it works fine.

I have also added a data validation warning feature to the cell so that when the user enters a name that is not recognized he is warned and can either proceed (if he needs to type a new name) or cancel and re start typing. This also works fine : when entering a wrong name, the warning appears as it should.

Here is the problem : when double clicking on the cell, the autocomplete dropdown appears, then I can type an incorrect name, press enter and ... this is not picked up by the data validation warning feature.

I am clueless and hope one of you guys can crack this one !

Samy

Comment: *hope one of you guys can crack this one* - hard to crack anything **without seeing the actual code you have**